# "dse spark" fails after enabling DSE Unified Authentication

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I updated DSE to 5.1.2 and enabled DSE Unified Authentication.

When I run "dse -u xxx -p xxx spark", I get a shell, but if i submit a query using "spark.sql" I get an error:

```
scala> val result = spark.sql("SELECT id FROM xxx.yyy")
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.datastax.bdp.fs.client.InternalServerException: Server returned HTTP error response  500 (Internal Server Error)
Caused by: com.datastax.bdp.fs.client.InternalServerException: Server returned HTTP error response  500 (Internal Server Error)
  at com.datastax.bdp.fs.client.DseFsClient$stateMachine$macro$1$1.apply(DseFsClient.scala:132)
```

In /var/log/cassandra/system.log I see:

```
WARN  [Native-Transport-Requests-2] 2017-08-31 12:05:29,057  DseAuthenticator.java:659 - Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
ERROR [dsefs-netty-worker-4] 2017-08-31 12:05:29,842 DSEFS RestServerHandler.scala:287 - [id: 0x1810ea2d, L:/10.225.155.31:5598 - R:/10.225.155.31:58006] RestHandler invocation failed
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
```

Any idea how to fix this. By the way, dse spark-submit works...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by enabling dsefs in dse.yaml.